# Control program other than iTunes with bluetooth headphones

Tags: macos, bluetooth, mediaplayer

I am using bluetooth headphones with OS X Lion.  The headphones (like most bluetooth headsets) have built-in play/pause and back/forward controls.  Using the play button will always launch iTunes, even if another audio player is running.

Is it possible to set the system up so that the bluetooth headset will control another audio player (in my case I want to use it with Spotify)?  Is there a way to "catch" the play action sent to the system and handle it myself somehow? (I'm new to OS X)

Comment: Any solution that works is welcome, no matter how hacky.

Comment: This seems to be something that has just recently become a problem: > Posted on ‎01-10-2012 Recently I've been listening to music on spotify on my Mac through my Bluetooth headset with no problems but last week spotify stopped responding the the buttons on my headset (play/pause, forward, back) and instead they trigger itunes, even when I am listening to spotify at the time! Source: [Spotify community](http://community.spotify.com/t5/Desktop-Mac/Bluetooth-headset-buttons/td-p/161796)