# How can I remap a play-button keypress from a Bluetooth headset on OS X?

Tags: macos, bluetooth, keybindings

I have an LG Tone (HBS 700) Bluetooth stereo headset, and am using it with OS X Lion.

The headset has a play/pause toggle button, but unlike my keyboard's play button, which will toggle play/pause for, say, VLC media player if it is running, the headset's play button will launch iTunes if it is not already open, or toggle play/pause in iTunes if it is already open. It will not toggle play/pause in any other media player.

Where is this mapping specified? Is there a way I can intercept the keypress event and remap it? I would like it to have the same behavior as the keyboard's play button.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Related questions: [469](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/469), [31925](http://superuser.com/questions/31925), [35916](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/35916), [52353](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52353), [58234](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58234), [62835](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/62835), [72700](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/72700)